# Reusing SSH key passphrase between multiple command lines

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, spawn

I'm using NodeJS to execute multiple git command lines. Updating submodules, pulling some projects, etc. Everything works but I have an inconvenient issue. When I perform two command lines, like this

```js
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

await exec('cd my/project/path && git pull');
await exec('cd my/other/project/path && git pull');
```

I'm forced to enter my SSH key passphrase two times. I tried `await exec('cd my/project/path && git pull && cd my/other/project/path && git pull');` but the result is the same (passphrase asked two times).

Is this possible to use the ssh-agent to keep the passphrase between the two command lines? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for at least linux environments:

```
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

await exec('ssh-add');
await exec('cd my/project/path && git pull');
await exec('cd my/other/project/path && git pull');
```